# Focus and select all input box after append of input box

Tags: jquery

I need to implement a generation input box, and upon generation there is a default value, that default value should auto focus and all text should be selected;

Here is my function in JS assuming a button has been click and call this function

```
function createFolder()
{
   var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr({   
                        "id" : 'TextBoxDiv',
                        "class" : 'TextBoxDiv+ctr'
                        });   
   newTextBoxDiv.html('<input type="text" name="folder_name" id="folder_name"   value="New Folder"/>');

   $("#folder_name").focus(function() { $(this).select(); } );

   newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#fileTreeView");

}
```

Comment: And I assume this is not working?
Try swapping the last two lines of code.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ IDs _must_ be unique

Comment: See my updated code below, which is what I think you want. Instead of attaching the select() event on focus, it will now focus() then select().

Answer (score 0):

`$("#folder_name")` will return empty when the element has not been attached to the document.

Try this:

```
function createFolder() {
    var newTextBoxDiv = $('<div id="TextBoxDiv"/>').addClass("TextBoxDiv+ctr");
    var input = $('<input type="text" name="folder_name" id="folder_name"  value="New Folder"/>').focus(function () {
        $(this).select();
    });
    newTextBoxDiv.append(input).appendTo("#fileTreeView");
}
```

And I assume the function will be called multiple times, then you need to make unique ID for these elements.

Comment: Hi xdazz, Yes I already created a counter so that all Input IDs are unique, but still focus and select all is not working

Answer (score 0):

Set up a counter somewhere to track the new IDs and insert the value into the newly added element definitions. And append the element before attaching an event. Swapping the last two lines of code in your function.

```
var folderCount = 0;

function createFolder() {

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr({
        "id": 'TextBoxDiv_' + folderCount ,
        "class": 'TextBoxDiv+ctr'
    });
    newTextBoxDiv.html('<input type="text" name="folder_name_' + folderCount + '" id="folder_name_' + folderCount + '" value="New Folder"/>');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#fileTreeView");

    $("#folder_name_" + folderCount).focus().select();

    folderCount++;
}
```